# Heroku Deploy; GET / POST error in Public > JS > app.js / angular.module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

Here is what is in my server.js file this seems to work fine until it ask for a GET / POST request from my Public > javascripts > app.js file (see below for app.js syntax

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');
var path = require('path');

// set the port of our application
// process.env.PORT lets the port be set by Heroku
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// set the view engine to jade
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client', 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

// set the home page route
// app.get('/', function(req, res) {

//     // jade render automatically looks in the views folder
//     res.render('index');
// });

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Here is my Public > javascripts > app.js file

```
angular.module('nodeTodo', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.todoData = {};

    // Get all todos
    $http.get('/api/v1/todos')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todoData = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        });

    // Create a new todo
    $scope.createTodo = function(todoID) {
        $http.post('/api/v1/todos', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.todoData = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            });
    };

    // Delete a todo
    $scope.deleteTodo = function(todoID) {
        $http.delete('/api/v1/todos/' + todoID)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todoData = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the endpoints for your API in your NodeJs application. 
In your code there is only a single get route for '/', and not the required ones in your AngularJs controller...

Try adding these to your server.js file:

```
app.get('/api/v1/todos', function(req, res, next) { ... }

app.post('/api/v1/todos', function(req, res, next) { ... }

app.delete('/api/v1/todos/:param', function(req, res, next) { ... }
```